# Can't implement a SortableJS plugin without referencing unexported symbols from `sortablejs` source code

Tags: sortablejs

I want to write a SortableJS plugin that gets mounted to a `Sortable` instance from the `sortablejs` package:

```js
import Sortable from 'sortablejs'
Sortable.mount(new MyPlugin())
```

However, looking at the shipped plugins, it looks like they depend on unexported symbols imported directly from the source code. For example `MultiDrag.js` imports `expando` from `../../src/utils.js`.

Can I write a plugin without referencing `sortablejs` source code?